# web request e json no c#

Tags: c#, json, firebase, webrequest

Estou trabalhando com o firebase, e estou buscando os dados do servidor com HttpWebRequest, consegui recuperar esses dados da seguinte maneira;

> {"-L1OD7LjENM8ZHSpS7NE":{"Idade":"18
>   anos","Nome":"vitor","Telefone":"11
>   970705570"},"-L1ODHPKmz_1zcCfpZwF":{"Idade":"10 anos","Nome":"joao
>   ","Telefone":"9898294792"},"-L1ODMFC92yisdG4UxPU":{"Idade":"30
>   anos","Nome":"bruno","Telefone":"9898294792"}}

Usando esse código abaixo;

```
HttpWebRequest pesquisar = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp(URL);
pesquisar.ContentType = "application/json: charset=utf-8";
HttpWebResponse pesquisar1 = pesquisar.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
using (Stream pesquisarStream = pesquisar1.GetResponseStream())
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pesquisarStream, Encoding.UTF8);

            var text = reader.ReadToEnd();

            richTextBox1.Text = text;
}
```

Eu gostaria de receber esses dados, direto em um arquivo json e criar uma lista pra poder manipular tanto os dados, quanto as keys.

Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você usa `ReadToEnd()` você vai até o fim do Stream e não volta. Se você quer mesmo ler todo o conteúdo de uma vez, armazene numa variável e só então utilize-a para manipular em outros locais. Quando você chama `ReadToEnd()` no Console, já esvaziou o buffer.

Veja se este [Documento](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend(v=vs.110).aspx) te ajuda.

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo de como implementar, isso melhoraria e muito a resposta.

Comment: É como o @wilson fez abaixo.